# Is it possible to send php variable via link to popup

Tags: php, ajax, popup

How can I get this link to open as a popup perhaps with ajax?

```
<a href="page.php?catId=<?php $row['catId'];?>&userId=<?php $row['userId']; ?>">
```

With the variables transfered to the popup.

I quite like the ajax modal popup, but don't know how to pass php varaiables.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use jQuery and it's section called data.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try it, but just one question; can I pass php variables with this?

Comment: yes, you can. something like
data: { name: <?php echo $name?>, location: <?php echo $location ?> }

Answer (score 1):

In page.php, you get the query string like this:

```
$catId = $_GET['catId'];
$userId = $_GET['userId'];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with the php side of things, my problem is the ajax/javascript side. I don't know how to create the popup and pass these variables through the link if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the link to javascript:

```
var myHTML= '<html>' +
'<body>' +
'<div>' + page.php?catId=<?php $row['catId'];?>&userId=<?php $row['userId']; ?> + '</div>+
'<!-- other html here -->' +
'</body>' +
'</html>';

var myPopup= window.open('http://www.domain_here.com/mypopup.html','mywindow','width=500,height=500,toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0');

myPopup.document.open();
myPopup.document.write(myHTML);
myPopup.document.close();
```